# Convert -dB to equivalent +dB

Tags: sound, decibel, amplitude

I asked this question on stackoverflow and stackexchange mathematics, but on both sites my question was closed and suggested to ask here as mentioned in the [comments to this question on mathematics.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3124867/convert-db-to-db?noredirect=1#comment6438343_3124867)

I am developing an android app which generates beep sound with vary frequency and vary  dB. User can set frequency and dB and then corresponding beep sound will be generated.

The problem is in android the sound volume change by amplitude which  is in range of 0 to 1 where 0=min and 1=max. So users give dB and by formula of

> amp = 10^(dB/20)

I convert dB to amp ... but in this formula the dB should be negative so formula gives amp in range of 0-1 but users select +ve dB and in this case all calculated amp is above 1 which in android is always max.

I want to know if there is any way to get -ve dB equivalent to given +ve dB.

Note: This app is about hearing experiment.

Comment: Hi! Welcome! I don't understand what do you mean by `-ve dB equivalent to given +ve dB`. Please provide more details.

Comment: You will need to subtract a number of decibels, unfortunately that number is unknown and different for every phone.

Comment: You simply need to define some baseline, some floor, as the power level. The math needs a REFERENCE level.

Answer (score 1):

Decibels are always defined relative to some reference. For instance, 0 dB corresponds to 1 x reference, and 20 dB corresponds to 10 x reference (using your formula). Your Android sound setting is simply a normalised value between 0 and 1, with 0 being completely silent and 1 being the maximum output the speakers can handle, and it has nothing to do with dB, positive or negative.

The problem is that you don't know what 0 dB (i.e. 1 x reference) corresponds to on that scale. I guess you could try to find out using the Android developer documentation, but I bet this value is just arbitrary and probably varies from manufacturer to manufacturer, so even if you find out for one phone it'll probably not work for others.

I suppose a way to fix this might be to first get the user to calibrate the reference by first recording the ambient background noise in the room they are in, which will allow you to set 0 dB and then output sound volumes with respect to that.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decibel here is the table that shows the dB and corresponding amplitude ... here my app works only in negative range of dB :(... so after checking this table i think its not normalized ... but i am not sure

Comment: There is no Android standard saying how loud the speaker output is (or has to be.)

Comment: @RouzbehZarandi, the "amplitude ratio" on that Wikipedia page has nothing to do with what Android calls amplitude. The amplitude ratio is defined as the square root of the power ratio, 10 * log(dB), where dB is the value in decibels. The power ratio is 20 * log(dB).

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution is to live with negative numbers.  0dB is full volume, negative numbers are quieter.

That is how the fader controls on audio mixing boards work.  Zero at the high end for full volume, minus infinity at the bottom for muted.

If negative numbers bother you (or your users,) just add 100 to the displayed value.  The on screen scale runs from 100 ( full volume) down to zero (not quite really muted, but close enough.)

You then subtract 100 from that value when you calculate the percentage of full scale to drive your output.

As long as you are using one phone and set of headphones, it doesn't matter really what the numbers are.  You can compare relative hearing sensitivity just by comparing the values - and it doesn't matter whether they range from 0dB full volume to -100dB or from 100dB full volume to zero dB.  All that matters is that you use the same scale on the same hardware.  Then all of your measurements will be comparable.

---

If you need to use more than one phone and set of headphones things get to be tricky.

You will need to calibrate each phone and headphone combination.

You would have to have a calibrated sound pressure level meter.

You would have each phone generate a particular tone at a given fraction of full scale (but **not** at full scale) and you would measure the real volume using your sound pressure level meter - with the meter's microphone at a set distance from the headphone speaker in an anechoic chamber to make sure you are only measuring the sound from the one headphone.

You would do that for each tone that you want to use in your experiments, and at several volume settings.

From the collected data, you make calibration curve.  You use that to calculate the real generated sound pressure level for each tone, using the fraction of full scale volume you are generating.

As you can see, this gets complicated rather quickly.

The volume has to be calibrated because there is no direct relation between the digital full scale volume and the generated sound pressure level.  It depends on the amplifiers used in the phone and the efficiency of the headphone.

You have to calibrate by frequency and volume because speakers aren't equally efficient at all frequencies.  This is why some speakers have poor bass (inefficient at low frequencies) or poor treble (inefficient at high frequencies.)

---

You could skip the calibration if you use identical models of phones and identical models of headsets.  You will have some variation (headphones and amplifiers will never be exactly identical even for identical models) but the variations should be smaller than what you are trying to measure.  I say that because listening tests are all to some extent subjective - testing the same person several times will get results that vary by fairly large amounts.  A couple of dB difference between (nearly) identical devices shouldn't matter much.

If you need your data to be comparable to other studies or to professional testing equipment, then you will have to do calibration.  If all of your test setups use identical hardware, then you could generate one set of calibration data and handwave the differences between individual devices - use the same calibration curve for all sets of identical hardware.

---

If this is part of a university (or other school) project, you should as your instructor for guidance.

- Do you need calibration?
- Do you need multiple sets of hardware?
- Can all hardware be identical?
- Do your results need to be comparable to other experiments or tests?

---

If the idea is for people to download your program and do your test on just any old phone and headphone setup then there's no way for you to get usable results.

Every combination of phone and headphone is unique - there is no "one size fits all" calibration that you could use to compare results from my Motorola phone with cheap earphones to the results from somebody with a Samsung phone and Dr. Dre $100 earphones.  The variations in hearing ability will be masked by the variations in output levels of the various phone/earphone combinations.

Answer (score 0):

As you want to generate a beep, the cleanest way to present the user interface is to have your 0dB reference level be the loudest possible level the phone can generate. Then the user enters lower amplitudes as -20dB etc. The reference level is somewhat arbitrary, but consistent for any one phone.

If you instead wanted to have a more 'acoustically valid' scenario where 0dB SPL (sound pressure level) corresponds to the threshhold of hearing (nominally 20uPascal rms), then you will have a nightmare for calibration, do you calibrate every phone, have the user calibrate it, nightmare.

Once you've chosen your reference level, match that to how you can request levels from the phone. Are its dBs level (+ve is louder) or attenuation (+ve is quieter)? Once that's sorted out, converting from one to the other is simply a case of using a minus sign.